# Android access MvxDialogFragment view from service

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-dialogfragment

I am using MVVMCross, and have a problem with MvxDialogFragment bindings.
I have a base service, which is resolved in Core PCL project, add custom services implementations in iOS and Android projects derived from the base service class.

In android service i construct and show MvxDialogFragment instance:

```
var top = (MvxFragmentActivity)Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;

if (top == null)
{
    throw new MvxException("Cannot get current top activity");
}

var dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(top);
dlg.Create().Show();

dialog = new MyDialog
{
    Cancelable = false
};
dialog.Show(top.SupportFragmentManager, "");
```

And i have simple dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/test_click_button"
        android:text="Test"
        app:MvxBind="Click TestClickCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So my goal is to acces base service commands from dialogFragment, which is instantiated from service. How can i do that?

As an alternative, i want to handle my button click in service, but cannot find a way to do this, because my View, ViewModel or Dialog properties are null.

How it's possible to handle clicks in service, or implement self binding?

Comment: If you want to access a view from a service, you are basically doing it wrong. Mvvm pattern is not made to do that. You also say "i don't want to place my service commands in any viewModel". Commands don´t live in services, but in ViewModels. ViewModels call service methods. Maybe I´ve just misunderstood the whole thing...

Comment: Thanks for reply! I edited the question, the main goal is: how to bind dialogfragment buttons to service commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i achieved the desired, through MvxDialogFragment subscription, and service injection:

```
public class MyDialog : MvxDialogFragment
{
    private ISampleService _sampleService;

    public MyDialog(ISampleService sampleService)
    {
        _sampleService = sampleService;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        EnsureBindingContextSet(savedInstanceState);

        var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
        var view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.MyDialog, null);

        view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.test_click_button).Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _sampleService.TestClick();
            Dismiss();
        };

        dialog.SetView(view);

        return dialog.Create();
    }
}
```